# Как преобразовать ссылку на картинку в картинку в PHP

Tags: php, api, twitter-api

Есть такой код АПИ запроса твитов с твиттера:

```
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "ххх",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "ххх",
'consumer_key' => "ххх",
'consumer_secret' => "ххх"
);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
if (isset($_GET['user'])) {$user = $_GET['user'];} else {$user = "ххх";}
if (isset($_GET['count'])) {$count = $_GET['count'];} else {$count = 3;}
$getfield = "?screen_name=$user&count=$count";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
if(array_key_exists("errors", $string)) {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}
foreach($string as $items)

    {
        echo '<a href="/" target="blank"><div class="tw">
        <div class="tw_title">'. $items['user']['name'].'</div>
        <div class="tw_date">'. $items['user']['screen_name']. '</div>'. '&nbsp;&nbsp; > '. 
        '<div class="tw_date">'. $items['created_at']."<br />".'</div></div></a>';
        echo '<div class="tw_text"><a href="/" target="blank">'. $items['text']."<br />".'</a></div>';
        echo '<div class="tw_pad">'. $items['user']['profile_image_url']."<br />".'</div>';

    }

?>
```

Есть код получения ссылки на картинку:

```
echo '<div class="tw_pad">'. $items['user']['profile_image_url']."<br />".'</div>';
```

Получаю вот такой ответ:

```
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1226855970246201345/F7jRYOAf_normal.png
```

Так вот нужно чтобы показывало не ссылку на картинку а саму картинку.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `echo '<div class="tw_pad"><img src="'. $items['user']['profile_image_url'].'"/><br /></div>';`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Да не за что. Удачи Вам в Вашем проекте.

Comment: Благодарю! И Вам удачи!